# Need help optimizing solution for Project Euler problem #12

Tags: java, optimization, primes, mathematical-optimization

I've been having my fun with Project Euler challenges again and I've noticed that my solution for number 12 is one of my slowest at `~593.275 ms` per runthrough. This is second to my solution for number 10 at `~1254.593 ms` per runthrough. All of my other answers take less than `3 ms` to run with most well under `1 ms`.

My Java solution for [Problem 12](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=12):

main():

```
int index = 1;
long currTriangleNum = 1;

while (numDivisors(currTriangleNum) <= 500) {
    index++;
    currTriangleNum += index;
}

System.out.println(currTriangleNum);
```

numDivisors():

```
public static int numDivisors(long num) {  
    int numTotal = 0;

    if (num > 1)
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            for (long i = 1; i * i <= num; i++)
                if (num % i == 0)
                    numTotal+=2;
        } else {
            // halves the time for odd numbers
            for (long i = 1; i * i <= num; i+=2)
                if (num % i == 0)
                    numTotal+=2;
    }
    else if (num == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (num == 1)
        return 1;
    else (num < 0)
        return numDivisors(num *= -1);

    return numTotal;
 }
```

.

Looking around the solutions forum, some people found that [these formulas](http://mathschallenge.net/index.php?section=faq&ref=number/number_of_divisors) (n = (p^a)(q^b)(r^c)... & d(n) = (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)...) worked for them, but I personally don't see how it'd be any faster; faster by hand, perhaps, but not in a program.

.

The basic thought process is as follows:

We want to calculate the number of divisors in 48. By looking at the factor tree below, we can conclude that `48 = (2^4)(3^1)` [n = (p^a)(q^b)(r^c)...].

```
  48
 /  \
2   24
   /  \
  2   12
     /  \
    2   06
       /  \
      2    3
```

Knowing this, we construct the formula `d(48) = (4+1)(1+1)` [d(n) = (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)...] to determine that 48 has 10 factors.

```
d(n)  = (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)...
d(48) = (4+1)(1+1)
d(48) = (5)(2)
d(48) = 10
```

.

How can I optimize my code? Are these formulas the best solution? I feel that finding all the prime factors, then implementing the formulas would take longer than the program that I already have in place.

Many thanks,

Justian

**EDIT:**

Before anyone starts posting links, I have looked around similar questions in SO without any luck - I just can't think up implementations of their methods that would run quicker than what I already have in place.

**EDIT2:**

My 2nd attempt at the Sieve of Eratosthenes (for Problem 10):

```
int p = 3, n = 2000000;
long total = 0;
boolean[] sieve = new boolean[n];

for (int i = 3; i < n; i += 2)
    sieve[i] = true;

sieve[2] = true;

while (p * p < n) {
    for (int i = p; i < n; i++)
        if (sieve[i] && (i % p) == 0)
            sieve[i] = false;
    p++;

    while (!sieve[p])
        p++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (sieve[i])
        total += i;

System.out.println(total);
```

Runs at `~985.399 ms` - not too much faster than other method, but hasn't been optimized yet. It works, however.

Comment: I don't think I can help... My naive, brute-force PowerShell solution almost broke an hour! :) Though this was run back in PowerShell v1, in which function calls were extremely slow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571488/project-euler-12-in-python/571526#571526 (60 ms in Python)

Comment: Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm should not use division. See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Java

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: I tried this method, but it turned out to be all too similar to my first failed attempt at Sieve of Eratosthenes. I didn't wait for it, but I'd approximate that it takes 10 minutes with 2000000 values, which makes sense considering how many times is runs through the LinkedList.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Use the underlying mathematical structure**, this will dramatically change your program's running time. This also applies to problem 10, by the way; if you can't do it in a few milliseconds, you've used a massively inefficient algorithm. In fact, I advise you to work on problem 10 first, because problem 12 builds on it.

I'm going to give a better algorithm for problem 12 below, but first, here's an observation that should speed up your program significantly. If two numbers x and y are coprime (i.e. they have no common divisor other than 1), then d(x·y) = d(x)·d(y). In particular, for a triangle number, d(n·(n+1)) = d(n)·d(n+1). So instead of iterating over the triangle numbers n·(n+1), iterate over n: this will significantly reduce the size of the arguments passed to d(n).

If you do that optimization, you'll notice that you compute d(n) twice in a row (once as d((n-1)+1) and once as d(n)). This suggests that caching the result of d is a good idea. The algorithm below does it, but also computes d bottom-up rather than top-down, which is more efficient because multiplying is a lot faster than factoring.

---

[Problem 10](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=10) can be solved by a simple application of the [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Fill up an array of booleans (i.e., a bit vector) of size 2000000 such that with `sieve[i]==true` if `i` is prime; then sum up the numbers for which `sieve[i]==true`.

[Problem 12](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=10) can be solved by a generalization of the sieve of Eratosthenes. Instead of making `sieve[i]` a boolean indicating whether `i` is prime, make it a number indicating *the number of ways in which it is non-prime*, i.e. the number of divisors of `i`. It is easy to modify the basic sieve of Eratosthenes to do that: rather than set `sieve[x*y]` to `false`, add 1 to it.

Several subsequent project Euler problems benefit from a similar approach.

One issue you may have is that in problem 12, it's not clear when to stop computing the sieve. You can go two ways about it:
1. compute the sieve by chunks on demand, a worthwhile programming exercise in itself (this will require more complex code that the second method)
2. or start by *overestimating* a bound: find some triangle number that has over 500 divisors, you know you'll stop before or at that number.

You can gain more time if you realize that you only need to care about odd numbers, since d(2^k·n) = (k+1)·d(n) if n is odd, and finding k and n given only (2^k·n) is fast on a binary computer. I'll leave the details of that optimization as an exercise.

Comment: I will look into the 1st observation, but I've already tried problem 10 with the sieve of Eratosthenes with little luck. In fact, that implementation took 10 minutes to run on my machine. Of course, it's likely a programming error on my part, but I followed the instructions from the Wikipedia article to a T. +1 for an overall wonderful (non-spoiler, as Jim said) explanation. You certainly read my question correctly.

Comment: I will attempt these algorithms when I next find the time.

Comment: @Justian: I recommend you figure out what your sieve implementation is doing wrong, it's an important stepping stone (to solve project Euler problems, at any rate). Sanity check: did you notice that the wikipedia article has the loop repeating until p²>n, not p>n?

Comment: My original implementation looked similar to the one here: rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Java. My new one runs far faster than my first attempt and slightly faster than my old solution. I just need to optimize my new solution, which seems a lot more possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered breaking into prime factors, and keeping track of the primes so you don't have to recalculate them?

Comment: @Thorbjoern: I've thought about compiling a .txt file, as it would be much quicker than recalculating, but I feel as if this is cheating the system.

Comment: You can calculate them on demand and save the results as you go.

Answer (score 0):

I did this one a while ago, so I don't remember all of the optimizations, here are some:

1. use summation formula for sum(1...n)
2. find prime factors with methods
   described in problem 7 and problem
   10
3. determine how many divisors n has based on its prime factorization*

*Treat this as a probability question if you don't know the "rule".  E.g., you have four flavour-shots you can add to your coffee, how many options do you have?