# Triangle numbers in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to calculate the number of divisors for a triangle number.Here is my try.

```
tn = 0
list1 = []
for counter in range(1,8):
    tn=tn+counter
    for i in range(1,counter):
        if(tn%i==0):
            list1.append(i)
    print(list1)
```

I want to send the divisors to a list and count the number of elements in that list.But this program doesn't give the correct output.Please help me to solve this problem.

```
 1: 1           #of elements 1
 3: 1,3         #of elements 2
 6: 1,2,3,6     #of elements 4
10: 1,2,5,10    #of elements 4
15: 1,3,5,15    #of elements 4
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: 1: 1  #of elements 1
 3: 1,3 #of elements 2
 6: 1,2,3,6 #of elements 4
10: 1,2,5,10  #of elements 4
15: 1,3,5,15 #of elements 4

Comment: You can edit your original question with this information.

Comment: done.please don't reduce the reputation

Comment: Writing Python, not C: don't put parenthesis "()" around the if condition; you don't need to increment counter and i manually, the for loop iterator over range() is already doing this for you.

Comment: So I have edited the code but it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: What is you *exepcted* result, and what is the result you're *currently* getting? I see one result listed, but it doesn't say if that's what you want or what you're getting.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [this somewhat related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571488/triangle-numbers-in-python?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
def getDivisors(inputNum):
    result = [i for i in range(2, inputNum // 2 + 1) if inputNum % i == 0]
    result.insert(0, 1)
    if inputNum not in result: result.append(inputNum)
    return result

print getDivisors(1)
print getDivisors(3)
print getDivisors(6)
print getDivisors(10)
print getDivisors(15)
```

**Output**

```
[1]
[1, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 6]
[1, 2, 5, 10]
[1, 3, 5, 15]
```

`[i for i in range(2, inputNum // 2 + 1) if inputNum % i == 0]` is the same as

```
result = []
for i in range(2, inputNum // 2 + 1):
    if inputNum % i == 0:
        result.append(i)
```

Comment: I'm not sure a list comprehension will make much sense to someone who's just starting with Python. Also, it does mention Python 3, so I've changed the xrange to range.

Comment: @Evert Thanks man :) I have updated my answer with basic explanation.

Comment: Neat: a bonus list comprehension explanation/example.

Answer (score 1):

I altered your for loop and added an extra while loop to get it working.

```
tn = 1
increase=2
numbers=[]
divisor=[]
i=0

while i<15:
 tn+=increase
 numbers+=[tn]
 increase+=1
 i+=1

for i in numbers:
 divisor+=[i]
 print(i,":", divisor)
```

I made the code work up to the 15th triangle number not including 1. The while loop is pretty self-explanatory, it simply works out the next triangle number and adds this to the variable numbers. My second loop- the for loop- loops through the numbers in `numbers` and adds every number onto the variable `divisor`. Every time this happens, the interpreter prints  the current triangle number, as well as all its predecessors- which is what you asked for.

Run the code and see it for yourself, but next time think things through before you ask others, this is a fairly simple task.

Also, if you're adding a variable that's already been initialized, you don't need to write `variable=variable+n`, just shorten it to `variable+=n`and never put brackets around a conditional statement be it Python 2 or Python 3 (you would only do that in languages such as Java, Javascrip, C and C++)